# What are the best ways to promote our shiny new site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, 7-questions

Now that the site is in public beta, what are the best methods of promotion?

Here are forms I've already seen or posted myself:

- [Twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/StackRaspi)
- [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/duplicates/vbnlf/raspberry_pi_stackexchange_is_now_in_public_beta/) (Note there are two Raspberry Pi subreddits)
- [HackerNews](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4104635) (Whoops Alex!)

Comment: It has been [submitted since the public beta](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4133817), but didn't get much attention. We need a really good question/answer which that crowd would like for it to work there!

Answer (score 5):

> Pretty much copied from http://meta.libraries.stackexchange.com/a/109
>
> Related questions on other new sites: [Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131/how-do-we-promote-our-shiny-new-site/), [Libraries](http://meta.libraries.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-do-we-spread-the-word-about-our-awesome-site), [Chess](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/what-avenues-of-site-promotion-do-we-have-available/) , [WindowsPhone](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-do-we-promote-this-site) (these are some of our newer sites, you can probably find the [site-promotion](/questions/tagged/site-promotion) questions on the older ones if you want. Or use [this filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/49021/meta-site-promotion) I just created)

Few things you can do (some stuff taken from my post [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/what-can-i-do-for-this-site)):

- Create a community promotion ad and post on a graduated site. Maybe on [SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132988/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2012) and/or [SU](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3957/community-promotion-ads-2012). **[Unix](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/814/community-promotion-ads-2012) is another site that occurred to me--seeing that you guys have a site overlap.** [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/what-would-be-a-good-community-promotion-ad) and [chem.SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/140/22) have done so on Physics.
- Create an A4(or whatever) poster for your users to print out and stick somewhere. [We did that on chem](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/134/22)
- Write an awesome blog post, like [this one by a TW mod](http://www.thickbook.com/2012/02/dear-stackexchange-will-you-be-my-valentine/)
- Encourage colleagues/classmates/friends(who use/program RPi) to join. Tell them how awesome we are!
- Try to get more experts engaged. Remember, the more experts you have, the better the site is (we don't want to degrade into Yahoo! Answers)
- Retweet the upvoted questions posted by [@StackRaspi](http://twitter.com/#!/StackRaspi). This spreads the word about the site pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

And don't forget to mention the site in your Facebook feed - especially when posting pictures of cool RPi hacks.